# Pascal - Initializing class variable array

Tags: arrays, class, initialization, pascal

I have a trouble initializing dynamic array in a class. Class looks like this:

```
MyClass = class
    private
       var
         myVar: array of array of real;
    public
      constructor Create();
      procedure MyMethod(i, j: integer);
end;
```

Now I'm trying to initialize `myVar` in `MyMethod()` (after `Create()` was called).

```
procedure MyClass.MyMethod(i, j: integer);
begin
  SetLength(myVar, i, j);
end;
```

This raises 'Access violation reading from address'. I made sure the integers passed are valid so that is not the problem.

Note that when I try to do the same with local variable it works without an issue. Thanks for help.

Edit:

Since requested, here is whole code. It is an window app that is supposed to load a matrix from a text file, perform a Gaussian elimination and than save it to a text file. Originally I made the question more generic but my problem is with `SaveToFile` function.

Unit1:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, Unit2;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    OpenB: TButton;
    SaveB: TButton;
    GaussB: TButton;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OpenBClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SaveBClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    M: TMatrix;
  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.OpenBClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  path: string;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute()then
  begin
    path:= OpenDialog1.FileName;
    M.LoadFromFile(path);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  M.Create();
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveBClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  path: string;
begin
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    path:= SaveDialog1.FileName;
    M.SaveToFile(path);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Unit2:

```
unit Unit2;

{$mode ObjFPC}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type
  TMatrix = class
    private
       var
         matrix: array of array of real;
    public

      constructor Create();
      procedure LoadFromFile(path: string);
      procedure SaveToFile(path: string);
  end;

implementation

constructor TMatrix.Create();
begin

end;

procedure TMatrix.LoadFromFile(path: string);
var
  rows, cols, num, i, j: integer;
  f: TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(f, path);
  reset(f);

  read(f, rows);
  readln(f, cols);
  SetLength(matrix, rows, cols);

  try
    for i:= 0 to rows - 1 do
    begin
      for j:= 0 to cols - 1 do
      begin
        read(f, num);
        matrix[i, j]:= num;
      end;
      readln(f);
    end;
  except
    raise Exception.Create('Matrix size is incorrect or file is corrupted!');
  end;
  close(f);
end;

procedure TMatrix.SaveToFile(path: string);
var
  num: real;
  i, j: integer;
  f: TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(f, path);
  rewrite(f);

  for i:= 1 to length(matrix) do
    begin
      for j:= 1 to length(matrix[0]) do
      begin
        num:= matrix[i, j];
        write(f, FloatToStr(num) + ' ');
      end;
      writeln(f);
    end;
  close(f);
end;

end.
```

Comment: You don't show calling code, so my guess is you didn't create the class before using it ?

Comment: Yes, I did create the class first. If I did not, local variable would not work too.

Comment: So, please show the complete code, including your calls to `Create` and `MyMethod`

Comment: Alright, I uploaded whole code.

Comment: Sorry for asking you to upload the complete code. I was about to also ask you to read [mre], but it escaped me.

Comment: Find a basic Pascal tutorial, so that you learn the basics. Otherwise, you're going to just be flailing around trying to fix problems all the time, instead of actually getting anything done.

Comment: @KenWhite you are not being helpful. If you knew the mistake I made, you should have just post the answer instead of assuming what I know

Comment: I can tell what you know (and don't know) by the mistake you made here, which is made by people who have no idea what they're doing and are just hammering on the keyboard. You'll get much more accomplished if you take the time to go through a tutorial to at least learn the language basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to the constructor is

```
  M.Create();
```

which is wrong.

Try this instead:

```
M := TMatrix.Create;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, that is such a stupid mistake. Now works as it should.